# Buffon's Needle Problem

Tags: probability, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

[Buffon's Needle Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem)

**"Suppose we have a floor made of parallel strips of wood, each the same width, and we drop a needle onto the floor. What is the probability that the needle will lie across a line between two strips?"**

The solution for the sought probability $p$, in the case where the needle length $l$ is not greater than the width $t$ of the strips, is $\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot \frac{l}{t}$

So far so good.

**What I don't understand:**

Let's go back to the basics:

The probability of an event $E = P(E)$

$$P(E) = \frac{n}{N}\\  
n = \text{Number of outcomes that count as event }E\\ 
N = \text{Total number of outcomes.}$$

An example:

What is the probability of drawing a white ball from a bag that contains $3$ white balls and $2$ black balls?
Probability of drawing a white ball $= P(W)$, with $n = 3, N = 5$.
$$P(W) = \frac{n}{N} = \frac{3}{5}$$

Notice $P(W)$ is (a) *rational* (number) which indicates *outcomes* can *only be positive integers* and so (?) probabilities can only be *rational numbers*.

How come there's a *noninteger* number of outcomes in the solution to Buffon's needle (there's a $\pi$ in the denominator, which I understand to mean that if $t = 1$ then the *sample space (total number of possible outcomes)* is $3.14159\dots$??? How?

Comment: Here , we do not have a finite number of possible outcomes. There are infinite many possibilities where the needle lands and how.

Comment: I see. Then shouldn't N = $\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the number $N$ of outcomes is finite (so the number $n$ of outcomes that "lead to E" is also finite) and **all outcomes are equally likely**, then you can use the formula

$P(E) = n / N$.

However, in more general case (either with $N$ being infinite and/or having different probabilities for each "small event"), the formula above should be read as

$P(E) = $ mass of outcomes that lead to E / total mass of outcomes.

By definition, the total mass of outcomes, i.e., probability of the event that always happens, is 1, so the formula is actually

$P(E) = $ mass of outcomes that lead to E.

How exactly is this "mass" computed, is another question. See [Wikipedia page for Probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) and dive into

- discrete ones (where you can "count" events as in your suggestion),
- continuous ones (where you need integrals).

Comment: I think I get it. It's kinda like calculating the probability of hitting the bullseye. If we use *points* (infinite) we end up with the *nonsense* $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, but if we use *area* (finite), we have an "acceptable" solution. Am I correct? In Buffon's Needle problem, we're using the 1-dimensional counterpart to area, viz. *length*.

Comment: I read somewhere that, in re *probability distribution* of a *continuous variable*, that the probability for a specific x is 0. That only probabilities of a given *interval* can be calculated.

Comment: @AgentSmith Your last comment is exactly right.  So, to take a simpler specific example, suppose that at random, you draw a ray in $~R^2,~$ with it's endpoint at $~(0,0).~$  Then you define $~\theta~$ to be the angle formed by this ray, and the line segment $~\overline{(0,0), (1,0)}.~$  You could then ask what the probability is that $~0^\circ \leq \theta \leq 30^\circ,~$ (within a modulus of $~360^\circ$).  Then, you could reason that since (at random), $~\theta \in [0^\circ, 360^\circ),~$ the probability is $\displaystyle \frac{30^\circ - 0^\circ}{360^\circ - 0^\circ} = \frac{1}{12}.$

Comment: @AgentSmith Yes, you are right: if you assume that all outcomes are equally probable in darts, then "the mass" of the bullseye is proportional to its area (and the same in 1D).